# TYPO3's realurl in multi domain environment

Tags: typo3, realurl

Realurl generates the page URIs from the page title. In a multidomain environment there happen to be some pages with the same title, like "contact" or "imprint". It seems as if realurl cannot discriminate those URLs:

http://www.domain1.com/contact/
http://www.domain2.com/contact/

They always lead to the first URL found in the realurl database table, in the example above "http://www.domain1.com/contact/". Is there a way to avoid this?

This is the reaurl configuration:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']=array(
    '_DEFAULT' => array(
        'init' => array(
            'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
            'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
        ),
        'pagePath' => array(
            'rootpage_id' => '123',
        ),
        'fileName' => array(
            'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
            'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
            'index' => array(
                'print' => array(
                    'keyValues' => array(
                        'type' => 98,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'www.domain1.de' => '_DEFAULT',
    'domain1.de' => 'www.domain1.de',
    'www.domain2.de' => '_DEFAULT',
    'www.domain2.de' => array(
        'pagePath' => array(
            'rootpage_id' => '456',
        ),
    ),
    'domain2.de' => 'www.domain2.de',
);
```

Comment: Hey @stefan, check out this link https://gist.github.com/lorenzulrich/7147678 Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct snytax:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'] = array(
    'init' => array(
        'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
        'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
    ),
    'pagePath' => array(
        'rootpage_id' => '123',
    ),
    'fileName' => array(
        'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
        'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
        'index' => array(
            'print' => array(
                'keyValues' => array(
                    'type' => 98,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['www.domain1.tld'] = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['domain1.tld'] = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['www.domain1.tld'];

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['www.domain2.tld'] = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['www.domain2.tld']['pagePath']['rootpage_id'] = '456';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['domain2.tld'] = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['www.domain2.tld'];
```

The current realurl configuration can be found with the module "Configuration" -> $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'. There it can be checked whether the realurl configuration file does what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this means that `rootpage_id` settings is either incorrect or not set in your config. RealURL does not have any issues when you have the same titles for various domains as soon as you configured root page ids correctly.

Comment: I added a configuration example. What's wrong with it?

Comment: All wrong. PHP is not typoscript. This `'www.domain2.de' => '_DEFAULT',    'www.domain2.de' => array( 'pagePath' => array( 'rootpage_id' => '456',
        ),
    ),`

It means you have only `pagePath` and nothing else for this domain.